# What driving or racing video game is Trey (Joseph Gordon-Levitt) playing in Poker Face S01E09?

Tags: game-identification

In [season 1, episode 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_from_Shit_Mountain) of the TV show *[Poker Face](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_Face_(TV_series))* (2023), titled "[Escape from Shit Mountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_from_Shit_Mountain)," Trey Nelson (played by Joseph Gordon-Levitt) is shown playing a VR driving or racing game. The player character is driving a yellow SUV in an episode-appropriate snowy location. The game's UI features a minimap, a speedometer, and a (lap?) timer.

Animated GIFs and a screenshot of the game being played:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

##### What video game is Trey playing in *Poker Face* S01E09?

Comment: Parts of the HUD seem similar to Need for Speed Heat (example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/97OT0.jpg), but not all of it (the minimap is close, but the "North" indicator isn't the same, and the nitrous bottles are missing from the speedo, plus a whole lot of other HUD elements from the screenshot aren't present).  The car being driven also appears to be a [Lamborghini Urus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamborghini_Urus) which doesn't seem to appear in Need for Speed Heat according to the game wiki: https://nfs.fandom.com/wiki/Lamborghini_Urus  And also, the game doesn't seem to support VR.

Comment: While the right side UI elements are definitely from NFS Heat, it's definitely not it, since no part of the map has snow. I can also confirm that none of the new NFS games (including Heat) support VR. By the physics showcased in the GIFs, I'm leaning towards this being a fake game created just for the show.